Adding condition for comparing Guid on breakpoint using Visual Studio 2022
I am still learning debugging tools on Visual Studio 2022. How do you use the conditional option on breakpoint to compare values with Guid.
I want to use the capabilities of debugging tools in order to minimize writing temporary codes for debugging and it may be useful for debugging loops.
I tried this, but did not work.
Photo: Conditional Breakpoint
At the end, I just write if statement code then breakpoint it.

If the breakpoints conditions are not hit, please check if the value id has been assigned and meets the if condition.


I tried this, but did not work

Do you mean the breakpoint you have set Conditions not hit ?
If so, please add the variable id to Watch Window to check the value has updated to the new. From looking at your screenshot, looks like the variable id has not updated to entity.Id, but you have  set a condition for it.
id.ToString().ToUpper() =="A79xxx"

Actually, at this point in time, the value of id is null because the assignment statement has not yet been executed.
null == "A79xxx"

You need set breakpoint conditions after the variable has been assigned.
For example


Yes, you are right, the value is not yet set and the ToString() works on comparison not Guid. Thanks!
